# How to show more of the datasource fields in the Kendo UI popup editor, but not in the grid

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Looks like this has been "sorta" asked - but not quite.  So here goes...

Have a Kendo UI grid.  Working great.  Want to edit in a "popup" the record that is selected. That works great as well.  However, there are many more fields in the record than what I am showing in the grid.

So can someone explain how to create a full edit form in the popup, and not have to display all the fields in the grid?

Using PHP for this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [editable.template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-editable.template) option of the grid. You have to implement it in JavaScript though.